# Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents when choosing image from gallery

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-intent, android-espresso

I try to make UI test for picking image from gallery.
I have the following code:

```
 @Rule
 public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> intentsRule = new IntentsTestRule<FeaturesActivity>(MyActivity.class);

 private Instrumentation.ActivityResult mActivityResult;

 @Before
 public void setImageUri() {
        Resources resources = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getResources();
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + resources
                .getResourcePackageName(
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher) + '/' + resources.getResourceTypeName(
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher) + '/' + resources.getResourceEntryName(
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        Intent resultData = new Intent();
        resultData.setData(imageUri);
        mActivityResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
    }

 @Test
 public void test_selectPhotoFromGallery() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {


        //Setup the intent
        Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK),
                hasData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI));
        Intents.init();
        intending(expectedIntent).respondWith(mActivityResult);

        onView(withId(R.id.btn_change_photo)).perform(click());

        intended(allOf(expectedIntent));
        Intents.release();
    }
```

Click listener:

```
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
actionIntent.setType("image/*");
fragment.startActivityForResult(actionIntent, 2);
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

IntentMatcher: ((has action: is "android.intent.action.PICK" and has data: is content://media/external/images/media))

Matched intents:[]

Do you any idea why is this happening?

Cheers!

EDIT:

If I remove `actionIntent.setType("image/*");` the code works fine. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Can you provide the code for what occurs when clicking on the button with id: R.id.btn_change_photo in your code?  and ideally what you are trying to test for this particular test.  Normally, when testing using Espresso Intents, your test will either have an 'intending()' block or an 'intended()' block, not typically both.

Comment: @jdonmoyer It is my first UI test, so I have no previous experience. I am trying to simulate getting dummy image from gallery and place it into imageview and check if the resource of the image view is the same as the chosen one. I updated the question with the code of the button click

Comment: The way that I would normally test this situation is to create at least two tests.  One would verify that the click emits the proper Intent using intended() the other would test how my activity responds to differing results using intending().  Be aware that there are limitations to what can be tested with Espresso Intents 2.2.2 see my comment about that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32131576/1821566 I haven't spent enough time with Espresso 3.x yet to see if that's been improved.